# Product Recommendation: Good job scheduler for windows servers?

Tags: untagged

Looking for a mostly-GUI tool that is low cost (less then $1k, but not required) and allows you to create scheduled tasks and jobs without writing vbscript, batch files, or powershell.  Something simple that speaks SMB/CIFS, SMTP, LDAP, etc. for such things as "delete some files based on a list of folders from this text file" or "disable all users with expired accounts" or "delete all disabled users not in this AD group".

I've seen some of the big multi-OS enterprise task automation systems and they just look way overkill.  We're a windows-only shop, Server 2003 or newer and there's got to be a simple non-agent based product that is drag-n-drop for some of this basic automation.  Today we use all three languages mentioned above, and the scripts are not as reliable as a workflow-based-tool would be.

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

We use a program called [Exact Event Manager](http://www.exactamerica.com/eventmanager/index.html) from Exact Software, which is a rebranded version of [KnowledgeSync](http://www.vineyardsoft.com/) by VineyardSoft. It's quite flexible, but gets hung up on extremely long-running SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for one myself.  Stumbled onto [VisualCron](http://www.visualcron.com).

This is one of the better tools i've found.  Very flexible, with lots of workflow/trigger/event/reporting features.  It lets you define environment variables, tracks credentials and certificates to allow it to run secure jobs, plus has a nifty systray tool to boot.  It's under $200 per machine.