# Windows Job Scheduler

Tags: windows, automation, task-scheduler, batch-processing

I'm looking for a Windows Server job/task scheduler for a small business. We need more functionality than the built in tools, including SQL Server Agent.  We need conditional execution and would like the package to be able to handle holidays and non-working days.

This is similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/41211/product-recommendation-good-job-scheduler-for-windows-servers).  One of the recommendations was VisualCron, which was close, but did not support business days/holidays.

Anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

VisualCron does have Time Exceptions which you can use to avoid holidays or weekends.  Additionally, you can use custom schedules as triggers to run a job ever hour during business hours only.

Comment: I e-mailed the developer who indicated that it could not likely handle our use case.  For example we need a job to run on the first business day of the month.  If the first of the month is a Saturday of a three-day weekend, we would want the job to automatically run on the following Tuesday.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing this the other way around: run the script daily, and have the script itself check whether today is a day on which it should do its thing.  Much more flexible, and you can use any cron system you like.